# am trying to use arrays or loops to simplify my code after drawing Seychelles flag with html canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm creating the Seychelles flag with html canvas and javascript to create a Web page using arrays and loops as appropriate. So far i have been able to draw the flag but now i want to add arrays and loops logic to my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <canvas id="flag" width="550" height="300" style="border:1px solid grey" >
        Your browser does not support HTML5.
    </canvas>
    <script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("flag")
            c = canvas.getContext("2d")


        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(0,300);
        c.lineTo(120,0);
        c.lineTo(0,0);
        c.closePath();
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle="#003f87";
        c.fill();

        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(0,300);
        c.lineTo(350,0);
        c.lineTo(120,0);
        c.closePath();
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle="#fcd856";
        c.fill();

        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(0,300);
        c.lineTo(550,80);
        c.lineTo(550,0);
        c.lineTo(350,0);
        c.closePath();
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle="#d62828";
        c.fill();


        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(0,300);
        c.lineTo(550,200);
        c.lineTo(550,80);
        c.closePath();
        c.stroke();

        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(0,300);
        c.lineTo(550,300);
        c.lineTo(550,200);
        c.closePath();
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle="#007a3d";
        c.fill();
    }
    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: am trying to use use arrays or loops to simplify my code

Comment: ok, that makes more sense - you should edit that into the question.

Comment: thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using an array of sections, each containing an array of points. I've also used arrays to represent the points but you might choose to use an object like `{x: 123, y: 456}` instead.

There are two nested loops, one for the sections and one for the points.

You specifically asked for loops, so I used `for` loops here. You might also want to consider `Array.forEach` for iterating through arrays.

```js
var sections = [{
  points: [[0,300], [120,0], [0,0]],
  color: "#003f87"
},{
  points: [[0,300], [350,0], [120,0]],
  color: "#fcd856"
},{
  points: [[0,300], [550,80], [550,0], [350,0]],
  color: "#d62828"
},{
  points: [[0,300], [550,200], [550,80]],
  color: "#ffffff"
},{
  points: [[0,300], [550,300], [550,200]],
  color: "#007a3d"
}];

window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("flag");
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var i, j, section, point;

  for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    section = sections[i];
    c.beginPath();
    point = section.points[0];
    c.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);
    for (j = 1 ; j < section.points.length; j++) {
      point = section.points[j];
      c.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
    }
    c.closePath();
    c.stroke();
    c.fillStyle = section.color;
    c.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="flag" width="550" height="300" style="border:1px solid grey" >
  Your browser does not support HTML5.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take. It loops through the points on edges for each segment:

```js
function drawTriangle(c, firstPoint, secondPoint, color) {
  var origin = [0, 300];
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo.apply(c, origin);
  c.lineTo.apply(c, firstPoint);
  c.lineTo.apply(c, secondPoint);
  c.closePath();
  c.strokeStyle = color;
  c.stroke();
  c.fillStyle = color;
  c.fill();
}

var c = document.getElementById("flag").getContext("2d");
var pointsOnEdges = [
    [0, 0],
    [120, 0],
    [350, 0],
    [550, 0],
    [550, 80],
    [550, 200],
    [550, 300],
    [550, 550]
  ];
var colors = ["#003f87", "#fcd856", "#d62828", "#d62828", "#fff", "#007a3d"];

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  drawTriangle(c, pointsOnEdges[i], pointsOnEdges[i + 1], colors[i]);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="flag" width="550" height="300" style="border:1px solid grey">
  Your browser does not support HTML5.
</canvas>
```

Comment: you had to cheat a little by taking out the black strokes though, right? Otherwise the red section would be split in two...

Comment: Yes thats true. I think your method is more powerful. I just wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

**For this particular drawing**, I think that the easiest way is to use `ctx.rotate()` after you moved the context's matrix to the bottom-left corner, and then just draw a vertical line before re-rotating the context :

```js
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var shapes = [['#003f87', 21.6],
              ['#fcd856', 27.7], 
              ['#d62828', 19], 
              ['#fff', 11.2],
              ['#007a3d', 11]
             ];

var y = canvas.height;

c.translate(0,y); // first move our context to the bottom-left corner

for(var i=0; i<shapes.length; i++) // loop through our shapes array
    draw(shapes[i][0], shapes[i][1]);

function draw(color, deg){
  c.fillStyle= color;
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(0,-3*y);  // move to the last point we drawn
  c.lineTo(0,0);   // go back to the bottom-left corner (now at 0,0)
  c.rotate(deg*(Math.PI/180))   // rotate the context by x degrees
  c.lineTo(0, -3*y);  // trace a vertical line outside our canvas
  c.stroke();
  c.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="300"></canvas>
```